# Cygwin bashrc package install error

Tags: cygwin, bashrc

Cygwin was unable to install a package. Is anyone able to advise with the details below?

```
Nisarg.Rajput ~

apt-cyg install bashrc

--2018-01-01 11:42:57--  http://ftp.ntu.edu.tw/pub/cygwin//x86_64/setup.bz2
Resolving ftp.ntu.edu.tw (ftp.ntu.edu.tw)... 140.112.36.185
Connecting to ftp.ntu.edu.tw (ftp.ntu.edu.tw)|140.112.36.185|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified
File ‘setup.bz2’ not modified on server. Omitting download.

bunzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
bunzip2: Invalid argument
        Input file = setup.bz2, output file = setup
bunzip2: Deleting output file setup, if it exists.
mv: cannot stat 'setup': No such file or directory
Updated setup.ini
Installing bashrc
awk: fatal: cannot open file `setup.ini' for reading (No such file or directory)
Unable to locate package bashrc
```

Comment: Did you remove or replace the`setup.ini` file (as shown error)?

Comment: I tried But with replacing but didnt work

Comment: `apt-cyg install bashrc` - are you attempting to use a hacked "apt" (ubuntu/debian install tool) for cygwin? - I recommend to read through the instructions on how to use it thoroughly. You're probably better off using cygwin's setup.exe in the majority of cases. Tip: Use the cyg* utilities to find the package that contains the *default* `bashrc`, reinstall that package.

Answer (score 0):

There is no package called `bashrc`

See full list on:
https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

Using cygwin setup you will have noted immediately.